# Add and Biding comboboxEdit DevExpress

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, devexpress

Im trying to bind one combobox from my class that i linked in the context

i have this in the control

```
 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Width="100" Margin="5" Name="cboProduct" DisplayMember="Name"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedProduct, Mode=OneWay,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          >

        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

[image: It shows this]

I filled the Combobox befor from code behind like this

```
var lsproducts = new List<Product>();
        var Products =_licenseService.GetProductList();
        Products.ForEach((x) => {
            lsproducts.Add(new Product(x.Name, x.ProductId));
        });
```

And im setting the SelectedProduct like this

```
 [DataMember]
    public License SelectedLicense {
        get { return _SelectedLicense;}
        set {                      
            _SelectedLicense = value;                
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedLicense");
        }
    }        

    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {             
            return new Product(_SelectedLicense.Product.Name,_SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
        }             
    }

        this.cboProduct.ItemsSource = lsproducts.ToArray();
```

in both cases im using the object Product

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using pd.Common.Domain;

namespace LicenceManagerWPF.Views
{
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductEnum ProductID { get; set; }

    public Product(string ProductName,ProductEnum ID)
    {
        Name = ProductName;
        ProductID = ID;
    }

}
```

i dont know why its not selecting the product when i open the window.

i have another one 
[![Shows like this][2]][2]

I dont know why its display the x mark, but when i chouse another licence it updated the combo selection

```
 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cboActivationMode" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}"                                       
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedLicense.ActivationMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  />
```

The second one its only a couple of enums values that fill like this.

```
 cboActivationMode.Items.Add(
            new DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ComboBoxEditItem()
            { Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(ActivationMode), ActivationMode.Online), Tag = ActivationMode.Online });
```

How can i bind the values to a combobox?
Regards

```
        cboActivationMode.Items.Add(            
            new DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ComboBoxEditItem()
            {Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(ActivationMode), ActivationMode.Offline),Tag = ActivationMode.Offline});
```

I tryed to do this

```
 public partial class LicenseDetail : UserControl
{
    private readonly LicenseService _licenseService;
    public LicenseDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _licenseService = new LicenseService();            
        FillCombos();
    }

    private void FillCombos()
    {
        FillProducts();
        FillActivationMode();
        //var str = Enum.GetName(typeof(ProductEnum), ProductEnum.CDSAddIn);
        //this.cboProduct.ItemsSource = new string[] { str };
    }

    private void FillProducts()
    {

        var Products = _licenseService.GetProductList();
        cboProduct.ItemsSource = Products;            
    }
```

The product list is a list of Iproduct (interface), i dont get i why they made it like this but each product is diferent they implement the same baseclass and the interface

```
[DataContract]
public class ProductList : List<IProduct>
{
    public bool Contains(ProductEnum productId)
    {
        return this.Any(x => x.ProductId == productId);
    }

    public IProduct GetProduct(ProductEnum productId)
    {
        return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == productId);
    }

    public void Remove(ProductEnum productId)
    {
        Remove(GetProduct(productId));
    }
}
```

I changed the combo to bind like this
     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProduct, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"

I create the property in the class like this
     public IProduct MyProduct
        {
            get { return _MyProduct; }
            set
            {
                _MyProduct = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProduct");
            }
        }

And assaing like this
     _CustomerLicense.MyProduct = SelectedLicense.Product;

this is how the list of products is filled
      public IProduct GetProduct(ProductEnum productId)
        {
            IProduct product = null;

```
        var connection = GetConnection();

        try
        {
            var sql = string.Format(Resources.GetProduct, (int)productId);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text, Transaction = _transaction };
            using (var rdr = new NullableDataReader(cmd.ExecuteReader()))
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var productName = rdr.GetString(0);
                    var featureId = rdr.GetInt32(1);
                    var featureDesc = rdr.GetString(2);
                    if (product == null)
                    {
                        switch (productId)
                        {
                            case ProductEnum.PDCalc:
                                product = new PDCalcProduct(productId, productName);
                                break;
                            case ProductEnum.PDMaint:
                                product = new PDMaintProduct(productId, productName);
                                break;
                            case ProductEnum.PBDynamics:
                                product = new PBDynamicsProduct(productId, productName);
                                break;
                            case ProductEnum.CDSAddIn:
                                product = new CDSAddInProduct(productId, productName);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (product != null)
                        product.Features.Add(new Feature((FeatureEnum)featureId, featureDesc));
                }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(connection);
        }

        return product;
    }
```

without any luck.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedProduct` property should have a public setter for you to be able to set it to the currently selected value in the `ComboBox`:

```
private Product _selectedProduct;
public Product SelectedProduct
{
    get { return _selectedProduct; }
    set
    {
        _selectedProduct = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
    }
}
```

And for the intial value to be selected, you either need to set it to a `Product` object that is actually in the `ItemsSource` (`lsproducts`):

```
viewModel.SelectedProduct = lsproducts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == _SelectedLicense.Product.Name && x.ProductID == _SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
```

Or you will have to override the `Equals` method of your `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductEnum ProductID { get; set; }

    public Product(string ProductName, ProductEnum ID)
    {
        Name = ProductName;
        ProductID = ID;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Product other = obj as Product;
        return other != null && Name == other.Name && ProductID == other.ProductID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mm8
I think the problem is that the combo its inside a control

Comment: inside a control and Product its a new object, i need to asign like this in the main window:
       _CustomerLicense.SelectedProduct = new Product(SelectedLicense.Product.Name, SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);

I think this is my problem.
Im filling the combo getting the products of the database and creating a new object Product, the original of the licence object is an IProduct that cannot be assigned because its an interface

Comment: Did you try to override the Equals method as I suggested?

Comment: Hi mm8, yes i did.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like this:

I created the method :

```
private void GetProducts()
      {

        var Products = new LicenseService().GetProductList();
        Products.ForEach((x) =>
        {
            lsproducts.Add(new Product(x.Name, x.ProductId));            
        });
        //this.cboProduct.ItemsSource = lsproducts.ToArray();
    }
```

Then i attached to the load of the main windows, where all the controls are

```
public frmCustomerLicense(CustomerLicenses cl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetProducts();
        _CustomerLicense = cl;
        grdLicenses.grdLicences.SelectedItemChanged += GridRowSelected;
    }
```

Then when one of the licenses is selected i set all the bindings

```
 var Record = (DataRowView)grdLicenses.grdLicences.SelectedItem;
            var SelectedLicense = (License)Record["License"];
            var list = new LicenseService().GetActivityLog(SelectedLicense.SerialNumber)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityDate)
           .ToList();


            _CustomerLicense.ActivityLog = list;
            _CustomerLicense.Features = new LicenseService().GetFeatures(SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
            _CustomerLicense.Products = lsproducts;
            _CustomerLicense.HasExpDate = SelectedLicense.HasExpirationDate;
            //_CustomerLicense.SetLog(list);
            _CustomerLicense.SelectedLicense = SelectedLicense;
            //_CustomerLicense.SelectedMaintenance = SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId == ProductEnum.PDMaint ? true : false;                                
            _CustomerLicense.SelectedProduct = lsproducts.FirstOrDefault((x) => x.ProductID == SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
```

And in my ViewClass i added this

```
 [DataMember]
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return _SelectedProduct; }
        set
        {                
            _SelectedProduct = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _Products; }
        set { _Products = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }
```

So, i set the combobox

```
 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Width="180" Margin="5" Name="cboProduct" DisplayMember="Name" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Products, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedProduct, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          >                
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Doing this works, thanks for your help mm8